# Best approach to programmatically replace XML in doc file using Java

Tags: java, xml

I have .docx files

I have the content in the docx file1.docx

```
<Name>John</Name>
```

I have another docx file called file2.docx

```
Hello <Name>!
```

How could I make it so I could read the contents between the tags and have a third file, file2.docx like this

```
Hello John!
```

I am looking into using apache poi, but is there an easy way to do this? I tried converting it into, but microsoft's XML is horrid. What java tools are best to do something like this? Thoughts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's i know POI is an API who can run on all operating system.
I mean it's the simplet way for manipulating Windows Word doc.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this with .xlsx files. Instead of generating the whole target file, create it using MSWord, put some place-holders in it and then replace the place-holders with your data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to not write XML in Word. Open the file and save as .txt, which is then a plain XML file that you can process easily.

Better yet, store your data (e.g. name `John`) in Excel, and change second document to be a "Mail Merge" Word template. Then Word (and Excel) can do it all without help from other tools.